# How to Get The List of IP Addresses of All PCs Connected in same network (wifi) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, networking

using this code i can find ip of my system but i want to get all the ip and name of the device connect in the network. i cant use any server side programming language like php c# as i need to operate the full system locally. Please help.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html><head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Network IP Address via ipcalf.com</title>
 </head><body>
  Your network IP is: <h1 id=list>-</h1> Make the locals proud.
 <script>

 // NOTE: window.RTCPeerConnection is "not a constructor" in FF22/23
 var RTCPeerConnection = /*window.RTCPeerConnection ||*/ window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

 if (RTCPeerConnection) (function () {
 var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]});
 if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {      // FF [and now Chrome!] needs a channel/stream to proceed
    rtc.createDataChannel('', {reliable:false});
 };

rtc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
    // convert the candidate to SDP so we can run it through our general parser
    // see https://twitter.com/lancestout/status/525796175425720320 for details
    if (evt.candidate) grepSDP("a="+evt.candidate.candidate);
};
rtc.createOffer(function (offerDesc) {
    grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp);
    rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
}, function (e) { console.warn("offer failed", e); });


var addrs = Object.create(null);
addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;
function updateDisplay(newAddr) {
    if (newAddr in addrs) return;
    else addrs[newAddr] = true;
    var displayAddrs = Object.keys(addrs).filter(function (k) { return addrs[k]; });
    document.getElementById('list').textContent = displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps ") || "n/a";
}

function grepSDP(sdp) {
    var hosts = [];
    sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) { // c.f. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#page-39
        if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {     // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-5.13
            var parts = line.split(' '),        // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245#section-15.1
                addr = parts[4],
                type = parts[7];
            if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr);
        } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {       // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-5.7
            var parts = line.split(' '),
                addr = parts[2];
            updateDisplay(addr);
        }
    });
}
})(); 
else {
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "<code>ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -d\" \" -f2 | tail -n1</code>";
document.getElementById('list').nextSibling.textContent = "In Chrome and Firefox your IP should display automatically, by the power of WebRTCskull.";
}

</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: There are many different tools which try to do this, but none are guaranteed to be able to accomplish it, and there are network configurations where it is just impossible. There is no foolproof way to do this because the network protocols were never designed with this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This isn't something that is available in general -- devices on the local network are not guaranteed to advertise themselves on the network, and may not have names at all -- and it is certainly not available to Javascript running in a browser.

Comment: @ManishSasmal - there are lots of network tools in every operating system - please specify which operating system you need this for - although, not really on topic in SO, because now you simply want to run a command on your computer

Comment: @ManishSasmal - if on the otherhand you are asking how to do it in a browser, then, as stated, you can't ... no way around it ... except with a browser extension/plugin/addon - but seeing as you are already in the location (LAN) that you want to see the other computers, may as well just use an OS tool, why re-invent the wheel - not sure why you want to see this in your browser anyway